# user control with databinding can't be used more than once

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I have a custom UserConrol in a Silverlight 3 application.  The control uses databinding for some properties, so I need to give it a name.   When I try to put more than one of these controls in my main silverlight control, I get a XamlParseException with the message "The name already exists in the tree".  How can I use this control more than once without losing the databound properties?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each instance in your main control a unique name.  The error is just saying that you're using the same name more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Give them different names, but still bind them to the same dataset.